# Object oriented programming loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, character, declare

I'm trying to do this exercise:

> Write a program that allows a user to input an integer n, followed by
>   n more integer values and display the sum of these n values.  The
>   program should then ask the user if he wants to continue.  If the user
>   answers ‘y’ or ‘Y’ the user will be allowed to enter a new value for
>   n, followed by n new values.  If the user answers ‘n’ or ‘N’, the
>   program should exit.

I can't solve this one. help please

```
import java.util.*;
public class breakloop
    {
    public static void main (String[]args)
        {
        int sum=0;

    do
        {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a new number: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        sum+=num;
        System.out.println("New Sum is: "+sum+ "\n");
        System.out.println("Do you wish to add more numbers? (y/n)");
        String c = new String();
        }
        while (c == 'Y');
    }
}
```

The error is:
C:\Users\Darren\Documents\NDIT yr 1\Oriented object

```
programming\Programs\breakloop.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
            while (c == 'Y');
                   ^
  symbol:   variable c
  location: class breakloop
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you declare `c` anywhere?

Comment: i think yes, by this code below
String c = new String();

Comment: Sorry, missed it at the end there. :) I'm no java dev but does `c` need to be declared outside of the do-while?

Comment: Declare it outside of the loop

Comment: i tried declaring it outside the loop, how to capture c inside the loop then? im new at programming, dont know much,